# How can I get ifttt to do automatic retweets that are formatted correctly?

Tags: twitter, if-this-then-that, retweet

I am trying to set up a recipe in [ifttt.com](https://ifttt.com) to retweet everything from account **samplesourceuser** to account **sampletargetuser** (I have control over both accounts, names have been redacted of course). The traffic/tweet levels are not high.

I have created a recipe which looks a bit like this:

[image]

(the twitter account configured in ifttt.com is **sampletargetuser**'s)

However, the `@` is always missed out in the resultant tweet from account B, which makes it look like `RT samplesourceuser: the tweet content`. I would rather than this follow standard retweeting format, so it looks like `RT @samplesourceuser: the tweet content`.

How can I do this with ifttt.com?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the @ is added by Twitter (because it is actually replaced by a hyperlink). I have gone through many recipes and played around with adding apostrophes and quotes - nothing seems to have worked.

In the end I created my own recipe, [Publish retweet with @](https://ifttt.com/recipes/289599-publish-retweet-with).

In place of Twitter, I am using buffer.com to publish. Buffer allows me to publish the username with the correct formatting. However, Buffer posts using a schedule and not immediately.